# Accessing gradient boosting tree weights in fitted model

Tags: scikit-learn

Gradient Boosting learns a function that looks something like this:

```
F(X) = W1*T1(X) + W2*T2(X) + ... + Wi*Ti(X)
```

where Wi are weights and Ti are weak learners (decision trees). I know how to extract the individual Ti (estimators_ property) from a fitted gradient boosting model in scikit-learn, but is there a way to extract the Wi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... the Wi's consist of the line-search estimate times the learning rate. 
In sklearn the learning rate is constant so its pulled out. In gradient-boosting there is actually one weight assigned to each terminal region (aka leaf). Those estimates are stored directly in the trees and updated during the fitting of the gradient boosting model (see [1]).

To access the estimates for terminal regions of the first tree do::

```
tree = gbrt.estimators_[0, 0].tree_
leaf_mask = tree.children_left == TREE_LEAF  # TREE_LEAF == -1
w_i = tree.value[leaf_mask, 0, 0]
```

[1] https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L197

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, since the weights are incorporated into the trees, the fitted GB model in sklearn is just the straight average of the individual trees? Because I thought I tried that and got a different answer than gbrt.predict.

Comment: no -- its a sum over the corresponding leaf estimates of each tree weighted by the learning rate

Comment: and dont forget the initial model (mean for squared loss; log-odds for log loss)

Comment: @PeterPrettenhofer Could you please explain why TREE_LEAF == -1 for terminal regions?